# Parallel Programming application

Tags: parallel-processing

I am trying to find an application used by any company  which uses parallel programing and the difference in performance they noticed between using sequential and parallel computations. Please could any one tell me a website or a list of papers which talk about such thing. Hani Almousli...

Answer (score 0):

For certain applications, CUDA can speed up tasks significantly.  Speeds increases of 1 or 2 orders of magnitude are not uncommon.  However, it requires certain NVIDIA hardware to run.

This can be a cost-effective solution if your problem can be tailored to work on this architecture.

The [CUDA zone](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html#state=home) lists many applications and the speed increase that was achieved.

Comment: It also requires problem structures amenable to the programming model CUDA hardware supports.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "if your problem can be tailored to work on this architecture."

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how important the company aspect is. There's lots of information in the research and scientific computing space on this.

The PALLAS project at Berkeley has taken a bunch of applications and parallelized them. Papers and more details here:

http://parlab.eecs.berkeley.edu/research/pallas

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~keutzer/

You can also look at the various Dwarfs project. These are 13 core parallel computation workloads:

http://parlab.eecs.berkeley.edu/research/193

There's a set of .NET implementations here. You can download these and play with them yourself:

http://paralleldwarfs.codeplex.com/

The CUDA Zone is definiely interesting if you want to use GPGPU hardware.

You can seem some results of an n-body code I wrote in C#/C++ with both serial and parallel implementations see here:

http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/04/seattle-code-camp/

This includes sample code for each approach.